# Replace part of URL in XML with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xslt, xmlstarlet

I would like to replace a part of URL with XMLStarlet.

`http://example.com:8081` to `http://example2.com`

**XML:**

```
<SHOP>
    <SHOPITEMS>
        <SHOPITEM>
            <IMGURL>http://example.com:8081/image.jpg</IMGURL>
            <IMAGES>
                <IMGURL>http://example.com:8081/image2.jpg</IMGURL>
                <IMGURL>http://example.com:8081/image3.jpg</IMGURL>
            </IMAGES>
        </SHOPITEM>
    </SHOPITEMS>
</SHOP>
```

As you can see the text I'd like to replace is on multiple levels in:

/SHOP/SHOPITEMS/SHOPITEM/IMGURL
/SHOP/SHOPITEMS/SHOPITEM/IMAGES/IMGURL

So far I tried:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//SHOP/SHOPITEMS/SHOPITEM/IMGURL/*[starts-with(text(), 'http://example.com:8081')]" -v http://example2.com input.xml
```

not worked... and:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//SHOP/SHOPITEMS/SHOPITEM/IMGURL/text()" -x "str:replace(., 'http://example.com:8081', 'http://example2.com')" input.xml

xmlXPathCompOpEval: function replace not found
Unregistered function
Segmentation fault
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: XMLStarlet uses libxslt, and since the EXSLT function `str:replace()` was [removed from libxslt in 2013](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxslt/commit/ae49d7a73b043bccb7631e7d9577bcaa0bbf8528) it has been unavailable. Perhaps you could consider doing something like `sed '/<IMGURL>/s/\(example\).com:8081/\12.com/' input.xml` or an awk alternative like `awk '/<IMGURL>/{sub("example.com:8081", "example2.com")}1' input.xml`.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `xslt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a real replace, but a substring trick. At least it works:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//*[starts-with(text(),'http://example.com:8081/')]" -x "concat('http://example2.com/',substring(text(),25))" input.xml
```